# How do I clear a textfield when dragging and dropping?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTextField in my app. I want to be able to drag text into the field from other apps. When this happens, I want my text field to erase anything that's already in it, and then show the text from the drag.

How do I do this? I can't figure out to know the text came from a drag. At the moment it just inserts the text whereever I drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way is to subclass it and handle the draggingXYZ methods that are part of any nsview

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I have subclassed my NSTextField and now receive drag events. Thanks!

Comment: cool that you found it based on that hint - I would have attached a bit more information but it was late and I was tired ;)